# I am developing firefox extension and wanted to count total number of text box of webpage but I wanted to ignore hidden textboxes. How to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox-addon

I am developing firefox extension and wanted to count total number of text box of webpage but I wanted to ignore hidden textboxes. How to do this? Every webpages has some hidden text fields for future reference so how to ignore them so that i can count only those text boxes which i can see.

Answer (score 0):

use input:visible to find all non hidden text elements

```
<!-- assuming you have included jquery-->
<div id="test">
<input type="text" hidden>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
</div>
<script>
alert($('#test').find('input:visible').length);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ff2Y/